# Can We replace ArrayList with ArrayDeque for better performance?

Tags: java, arraylist, arraydeque

I was reading Kathy sierra's OCP8 guide and found a line that says:

> "ArrayDeque is like an ArrayList with better performance"

Now I am confused about where to use `ArrayList` and where to use `ArrayDeque`.
I also know that ArrayDeque is always resized to a power of 2. On resize, the capacity is doubled, so this might be a performance hit in some cases. But I want to know which is preferable between the two.
  Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest use ArrayList over ArrayDeque on below cases

1. Use an ArrayList if you need to access elements by index and you only
   need to insert/delete at the end.
2. Use an ArrayDeque as a stack, queue, or deque.

Insertion and Deletion in Both Collection.

**ArrayList:**

Worst-case O(n) because you have to shift elements. Insertion/deletion at the end is faster because there are fewer elements to shift. If you insert when the Arraylist is full, you have to copy the elements into a new larger array, which is O(n).

- Insertion at the end of an ArrayList takes amortized constant time.
  This means that a sequence of n insertions into an initially empty
  ArrayList has a worst-case runtime of O(n), so the average runtime
  per insertion is O(1), although some insertions may be slower. This
  is achieved by always increasing the array size by a constant factor,
  because the total number of elements copied is the sum of a geometric
  series.

**ArrayDeque:**

- Deletion at the front or back is O(1), and insertion at the front or
  back takes amortized constant time. The JCF implementation does not
  allow insertion/deletion by index (if it was allowed, it would be
  worst-case O(n) because of shifting).
- Array deques have no capacity restrictions and they grow as necessary
  to support usage.
- They are not thread-safe which means that in the
  absence of external synchronization
- Null elements are prohibited in the ArrayDeque.

now answer is in your question. its totally depend on your requirement.after analysing you can easily predict.

for more please take a [look](https://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~mfried/cs313/list_comparison.html)

Comment: You say **Use an ArrayList if you need to access elements by index and you only need to insert/delete at the end.** But if we need to insert at ends , LinkedList is preferred over ArrayList.

Comment: @Codeninja exactly, but you need to traverse whole linked list. but you can do insertion using index method